# How to build OpenJFX and make a Maven artifact?

Tags: javafx

OpenJFX is built using Gradle.

On the [Building OpenJFX](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX) page, the build instructions talk about running `gradlew tasks` do show what the build is capable of doing.

One of the tasks listed on the web page is:

> publishToMavenLocal - Publishes all Maven publications produced by
> this project to the local Maven cache.

But if you run the command on a recent release, this option does not show up (many of the options do not show up).

The gradlew build appears to work, you get the jars in the build directory.

The question is how to publish these to local maven repository for use in my maven projects. I want to do this because the released OpenJFX jars appear to have been built with `-g:none`, so when debugging deep in the system, there's no information for the debugger. I'd like a local build with the symbols to facilitate debugging.

I'm sure I can just take a current maven artifact, and beat it into submission with the current jars, but I'd like to think there's a more formal way to do this.

Comment: Interesting. I'm pretty sure I've always had debugging information when using JavaFX from Maven Central or the SDK.

Comment: Ask the [openjfx-dev mailing list](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem? Asking for a friend :-)

Comment: @mipa No, I tried to get subscribed to the list, but got no response.

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle` you have to set `MAVEN_PUBLISH` property to true:

`defineProperty("MAVEN_PUBLISH", "true")`

If you do that, maven publish will be shown as available tasks and you can deploy maven artifacts to your local maven repository.

For example the graphics module:

`gradlew graphics:publishToMavenLocal`

Comment: When I set MAVEN_PUBLISH to true, I get the following error for 'base' and also for all the other projects (graphics, controls, swing, fxml, media, and web):
A problem occurred configuring root project 'jfx'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not find method classifier() for arguments [linux] on task ':base:modularPublicationJarLinux' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.